# locationManager:didUpdateLocations: delegate method not be call in second?

Tags: ios, core-location

I using the CLLocationManager to get user's location, code in the below:

```
if([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]){
    if(locationManager==nil)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
else {
    if(locationManager==nil)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 200.0;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

When app lanuched, and start location, the delegate method didUpdateLocations did called. I stoped location after I get the coordinate, code in the below:

```
if([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]){
    [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
else {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Because need to do other tasks, I used the above code to  restart location. Then the delegate method(didUpdateLocations) never get callback. The issue exists in iOS7 and iOS6. What I did mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Your which condtion going to execute. If your `CLLocationManager` using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges' In this you must have to wait for next location updates. CLLocationManger automatically  updates location when your device moved to certain distance.

Comment: But I haved stop location(stopMonitoringSignficantLocationChanges), after I get the coordinate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Once you stopped the location update then at what situation again you would start?